# Set the result of command to variable in Terminal post execution

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, virtualbox

**How can you set the output of a command run in terminal to a variable after it has run?**

### Background

(You can skip of you don't need the background) I run VirtualBox VM and do a lot from the command line, especially when I am remote.  `VBoxManage` requires either a UUID or the name of the virtual machine in order to interact with it.  For instance, if I wanted to power off a VM, the syntax would be (I have an alias set for VBoxManage as vbm):

`vbm controlvm <vmname>|<UUID> poweroff`

This is pretty easy if you have VM names that don't have spaces or special characters in them like "Client X Web Dev Server".  I do this so I can take advantage of descriptive names.  So, the tradeoff is that I use the UUID.  To do this, I created another alias that will `cut' the output down to just the UUID.  For example, if I am looking for my "Fred Web Dev Server" (I am a fan of the Flintstones), I execute the command:

`vbm list vms`

My output is as follows (shortened list):

```
"Fred - FreeBSD 10.2" {f93c17ca-ab1b-4ba2-95e5-a1b0c8d70d2a}
"FreeBSD 10.2 Master" {ae2a2d61-25e5-4b5e-b455-1b2f60b49157}
"Windows 7 Pro VL" {62bfbca1-9fb4-4758-aeac-2777f2614ffd}
"Windows 10 Pro" {46b285c3-cabd-4fbb-92fe-c7940e0c6a3f}
```

So, to interact with "Fred" I just issue the command:

`vbm list vms | grep Fred`

and as expected, I get:

`"Fred - FreeBSD 10.2" {f93c17ca-ab1b-4ba2-95e5-a1b0c8d70d2a}`

I then pipe it to another alias, `vmc`, that issues a "nested" `cut` command: `cut -f 2 -d { | cut -f 1 -d }`.  My result is just the UUID without brackets

`$ vbm list vms | grep Fred | vmc`
`f93c17ca-ab1b-4ba2-95e5-a1b0c8d70d2a`

**What I would like to do is set that result to a variable.**  What I have been doing is re-executing the command, but editing it first to add a variable set instruction at the beginning like this:

```
$ set vm=`vbm list vms | grep Fred | vmc`
```

Then I can reuse `vm` in my commands easily:

`$ vbm control $vm poweroff`

I like having the option of not setting the variable because there are times I don't need to use it, just see it.  I can redirect it, but that goes to a file.  I have tried to pipe it, but that requires another command.  Does anyone know how to do this?

---

**Update (5/20/16):**

I got much more out of this question than I expect to so thanks to @user3439894, @fd0 and @Mateusz Szlosek for their excellent suggestion.

I selected @user3439894' solution of using

```
vm=`!!`
```

because it was simple and elegant.  I assigned it to a shortcut key for when I needed it for even easier use.  However just reading the other answers, I now have some others solutions I can use for different scripting challenges I have run into the past.

Comment: After you've executed `vbm list vms | grep Fred | vmc`, and you want to immediately set the output of that commend to a variable, just type, e.g.  `vm=\`!!\`` and press enter.  To remove the `$vm` variable, use: `unset vm`

Comment: @user3439894 You should add that as an answer so I can upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to accomplish what you're asking is:

After you've executed `vbm list vms | grep Fred | vmc`, and you want to immediately set the output of that commend to a *variable*, just type, e.g.:

```
vm=`!!`
```

Then press enter.

To remove the `$vm` *variable*, use: `unset vm`

Answer (score 2):

What if you used a function defined in one of your bash startup file?

```
getvmid () {
/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxManage list vms | grep $1 | cut -f 2 -d { | cut -f 1 -d }
}
```

The `$1` is the first parameter of the function. It also limits the scope of the variable.

```
getvmid Fred
```

Setting the variable:

```
vm=$(getvmid Fred)
```

Untested but this should also work:

```
vbm control "$(getvmid Fred)" poweroff
```

Comment: I like this.  It never dawned on me that I could put functions in my bash startup file.  I will have to research this more.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the output from `vmc` to the `xargs` command line tool.

This will look like:

```
vbm list vms | grep Fred | vmc | xargs -I {} vbm control {} poweroff
```

You'll avoid assigning the output to the variable.

Comment: That a good suggestion, but I usually want to reuse the same uuid for the next set of commands, like `vbm modify $vm --vrde on` or similar....